# When does the energy depend on the magnetic quantum number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it only when a magnetic field is applied (Zeeman effect) or also with an electric field ?

Does the hyperfine structure's energy depend on $m$ ?

If $[H,\vec{L}] = 0$, can the energy depend on $l$ or $m$ ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the energy levels of for example the hydrogen atom don't depend on the magnetic quantum number lies in its spherical symmetry. In fact, the energy levels of a single particle in a *spherically symmetric* potential (including of course the Coulomb potential of hydrogen) is always independent of $m$. This is because in such potentials, the angular dependence of the eigenvectors of the hamiltonian in coordinate representation, can be solved without worrying about the specific potential. These eigenfunctions can be written as:
$$\psi_{nlm} (\mathbf x) = \frac {u_{nl}(r)}{r} \ Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$
Where $\{Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\}_{l,m}$ are the [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) and $u_{nl}(r)$ is just the eigenfunction of an effective one dimensional problem:
$$\bigg(-\frac {\hbar^2}{2m_e} \frac {d^2}{dr^2}+V(r)-\frac {\hbar^2 l(l+1)}{2m_er^2} \bigg)u_{nl}(r) = E_{nl} \ u_{nl}(r) $$
(see for example *[Introduction to Quantum Mechanics](https://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-David-Griffiths/dp/0131118927)* by Griffiths). As you can see, the above one dimensional eigenvalue problem, and therefore its eigenvalues (the energy levels) are completely independent of $m$.
 Now in general, any perturbation which breaks the spherical symmetry discussed above has the potential to make the energies depend on $m$. A magnetic field is one such perturbation, as it is associated by a distinct direction. As one might guess, this is also true for electric fields (the phenomenon is called the [Stark effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect)). The hyperfine structure also doesn't depend on $m$, but that is much more complicated than the above equations because it includes both electron and nuclear spins.

Comment: In fact, we only solved the hyperfine structure for the 1s orbitals, where l = m = 0. Since the energy depends on F = J + I = L + S + I, I had no real proof that the energy didn't depend on m_F. Btw, thank you for your answer !